# Rails select statement returns hash. What is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote:

```
Profcover.select("cover_name").where(username: username).last
```

and in logs it returns correctly:

```
SELECT  "profcovers"."cover_name" FROM "profcovers"  WHERE "profcovers"."username" = 'alizade'  ORDER BY "profcovers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

And when I paste it to SQL it returns correct answer. But when I paste it int code it prints not `/assets/covers/3.jpg` but `#<Profcover:0x007f9e6d2ca430>`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Profcover.select("cover_name").where(username: username).last.cover_name
```

`Profcover.select("cover_name").where(username: username).last` returns a `Profcover` object, with `<Profcover id: nil, cover_name: "....">` as content.